# What is return _gaLink(this,'#);

Tags: google-analytics

When tracking links, do i need to put this code at the end?

```
return _gaLink(this,'#');
```

What exactly doe it do? My understanding of this is not clear.

Comment: _gaLink is not a Google Analytics function. Maybe it's a wrapper you have to an analytics function. So if it's defined in your site please also post the code for _gaLink.

Comment: It's actually from the answer in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379615/onclick-for-google-analytics-and-target-blank-the-link-does-not-work Though I'm not clear why there's a second argument to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to tracking outgoing/external links? There is no Google Analytics function called `_gaLink`. Can you post up a snippet of your code?

`_link()` is used for X-Domain tracking, please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link)

If you simply wish to track "outbound links", i.e. links to other sites, then use this piece of code (not this requires jQuery):

```
///////////////////
// _trackOutbound
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href^="http"]:not([href*="//' + location.host + '"])').live('click', function(e) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound', 'click', this.href.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)/)[1]]);        
        _gaq.push(['t2._trackEvent', 'outbound', 'click', this.href.match(/\/\/([^\/]+)/)[1]]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello here is the code, thanks.<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email Link Clicked', 'http://www.exampleurl.org/', '#']); return _gaLink(this,'#'); ">exampleurl.org</a>

Comment: I have just updated my answer to include a snippet of jQuery that you can use without having to manually update all your HTML anchors. Just include that jQuery on every page.